# Reference of table in all databases of the Server

Tags: sql-server, reference, dependencies, sp-msforeachdb

I want to find the reference of particular table in all the databases of the particular server.
Example :
My query window is opened for **DB1** database and executed the query as:
**exec sp_depends 'dbo.table1'**
It return me all the references of the table **table1** in the database objects like (procedures,functions, triggers) of database **DB1** only but I want to know the references of the table in all other database on the same server without going to particular database query window everytime and running the query.

**exec sp_depends 'dbo.table1'**
I tried below statement for all databases but it did not work out:

DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

SELECT @command = 'USE ? exec sp_depends ''dbo.table1'''

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command

Comment: And what exactly does "it did not work out" mean? Did you read the documentation for sp_depends? Now would be a good time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that dbo.table1 does not exist in all your databases. So you need to validate that the database you are running against contains that table. Try this:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)

SELECT @command = 'USE ? IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'' AND  TABLE_NAME = ''table1'')) BEGIN exec sp_depends ''dbo.table1''; END'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```